# IS jmdns is working on Android? i am getting these errors when i run the jmdns class after calling it

Tags: android

I am working on android application, and I am using JMDNS for the service discovery. I used it successfully in a desktop application, but when I try to use it for android, it does not work. I simply made a class in main activity to start JmDNS:

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {     

            try { 

                System.out.println("Opening JmDNS");
                JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create();
               System.out.println("Opened JmDNS");

                ServiceInfo info1 = ServiceInfo.create("_tcp.local.", "SongsList",
                                                       1269, 0, 0,"Song" );

                jmdns.registerService(info1);

                 System.out.println("\nRegistered Service as "+info1);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}
```

Then start it in main:

```
new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
```

It does not work, here is the exception stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1280
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.jmdns.JmDNS
at com.example.testme.MainActivityClientThread.run(MainActivity.java:38)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jmdns.jar in your project's build (class) path.